# ingress configuration doesnt connect to service api in azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I have below configuration with one path for ui and another path for web api but api path doesnt work.

```
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: myingress
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
        appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-private-ip: "true"
        appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
        appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: /
    spec:
      tls:
        - secretName: mysecret
      rules:
      - host: dev-ingress.com
      - http:
          paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: uidev
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /gateway
            backend:
              serviceName: ocelotapigatewaydev
              servicePort: 80
```

uidev path works but ocelotapigatewaydev dot net web api is not working when i test the api with gateway/api.

Strangely if i have html at the root of the ocelotapigatewaydev web api project then it loads it..Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: what is this service ocelotapigatewaydev , does it have an http endpoint responding to port 80 , also you should be able to access the application at /gateway/api and not at ocelotapigatewaydev/api.

Comment: Sorry i was using the same. i corrected it. If i convert to run my web api to run as html it works.

Comment: What's the `api` path for `ocelotapigatewaydev`? Is it `/api` or `/gateway/api` ?

Answer (score -1):

Changing api calls path to below has fixed the issue

```
      - path: /gateway/.*
```

courtesy:

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/